# "expected unqualified-id before numeric constant" from #define ANSWERSIZE 5

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

Read many posts already but cannot see why this line of code is generating the error. This program is simple - it uses the I2C buss to allow communications from a MASTER Arduino UNO to a slave Arduino UNO.
The code below is the code for the MASTER and the definition, "#define ANSWERSIZE 5" is the line that the compiler does not like.

Program in entirety below:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#define ANSWERSIZE 5  // <--- THIS LINE GENERATES THE ERROR
#define SLAVE_ADDR 9

void setup() {

Wire.begin();
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("I2C MASTER Demonstration");
}

void loop() {
delay(50);
Serial.println("Write data to SLAVE");
Wire.beginTransmission(SLAVE_ADDR);
Wire.write(0);
Wire.endTransmission();
Serial.println("Receive data from SLAVE");
Wire.requestFrom(SLAVE_ADDR.ANSWERSIZE);
String response = "";
while (Wire.available()) {
  char b = Wire.read();
  response += b;
}
Serial.println(response);
}
```

Comment: The problem is most probably in Wire.h

Comment: `Wire.requestFrom(SLAVE_ADDR.ANSWERSIZE);` ...urks... does `requestFrom` take a floating point value? Why dont you use constants instead of abusing the preprocessor?

Comment: `Wire.requestFrom(SLAVE_ADDR.ANSWERSIZE);` is equivalent to `Wire.requestFrom(9.5);` Maybe it's supposed to be a comma `,`?

Comment: @JohnFileau not quite...

Comment: @idclev463035818 Well I *learned* something today then about `#define`

Comment: Definitely supposed to be a comma https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireRequestFrom

Comment: Thank you for straightening me out :-)  I tend to be anal about doing things the "right" way, but clearly this code is a bit "lazy".  I had gotten this code from an example on a YouTube video that during the video "appeared to compile" however it is quite obvious that what was compiled and working was NOT what was being shown on the screen.  Thanks again:-)

Comment: I also was not paying attention, nor had I used "#define" statements and just realized that they are preprocessor statements....again, thanks for pointing out that this is not the way things should be coded...btw, I couldn't agree more :-) :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can [look at the output of the preprocessor with `gcc -E`](https://godbolt.org/z/4_ixKH). For example this:

```
#define SLAVE_ADDR 9
#define ANSWERSIZE 5
Wire.requestFrom(SLAVE_ADDR.ANSWERSIZE);
```

will expand to

```
Wire.requestFrom(9 . 5);
```

And as `9. 5` is not a floating-point literal, you get the error. To fix it, do not abuse the preprocessor for something that wants to be / should be a constant. I'd like to say: "The preprocessor was never meant to be used like this", but unfortunately this has a long tradition and it is hard to get rid of old habits even when (nowadays) there is no good reason to do it.

Use constanst instead:

```
const int SLAVE_ADDR = 9;
const int ANSWERSIZE = 5;
const double COMPLETE_ADDR = 9.5;
```

or something more sophisticated if you don't like the repetition.

PS: I wasn't sure what `requestFrom` actually expects as the parameter, so I tried to be close to your code. Even if the correct call is `Wire.requestFrom(9, 5);` I would not use macros.